# В safari на мобильном телефоне нужно 2 клика вместо одного

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день. Есть сайт
http://sportzakupka.ru/goods/sport_iskusstvenaya_trava/
Если зайти с iphone из браузера safari, то рейтинг можно выставить лишь 2-мя кликами по звезде. Первый имитирует hovaer, второй - click. На ПК все работает как надо.

Вот код

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".rq_a .productRate").hover (
function(){
 jQuery(this).append("<span></span>");
},
function()
{
 jQuery(this).find("span").remove();
});


var rating;

jQuery(".rq_a .productRate").mousemove (
function(e){
 if (!e) e = window.event;
  if (e.pageX){
        x = e.pageX;
         } else if (e.clientX){
         x = e.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft) - document.documentElement.clientLeft;

     }
     var posLeft = 0;
     var obj = this;
    while (obj.offsetParent)
     {
         posLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
         obj = obj.offsetParent;
     }
     var offsetX = x-posLeft,
   modOffsetX = 5*offsetX%this.offsetWidth;
   rating = parseInt(5*offsetX/this.offsetWidth);

  if(modOffsetX > 0) rating+=1;

  jQuery(this).find("span").eq(0).css("width",rating*30+"px");

});

jQuery(".rq_a .productRate").click (
function()
{
 var vv = $(this).parent().attr( "id" );
 var d = vv.replace('rql', 'rq_'); 
 $('#' + d).val(rating);

 rt = rating*20;
 jQuery(this).html("<div style=\"width: " + rt + "%\"></div>");
 return false;
});

});
```

```css
.productRate {
 background: url(http://sportzakupka.ru/templates/sportzakupka//images/stars.png);
 width: 150px;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
.productRate div {
 background: url(http://sportzakupka.ru/templates/sportzakupka//images/stars.png) left bottom;
 width: 0;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.productRate span {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 background: url(http://sportzakupka.ru/templates/sportzakupka//images/stars.png) left center;
 width: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="prodrevsent">

   




           <tbody><tr>
          <td>
               <b>Внешний вид</b>
          </td>
          <td id="rql1" class="rq_a">

 <div class="productRate">
     <div style="width: 100%"></div>  
 </div> 
 <input name="rq[1]" id="rq_1" type="hidden" class="rfield" value="5">  
 
    </td>
           </tr>



           <tr>
          <td>
               <b>Фиксация волокна</b>
          </td>
          <td id="rql2" class="rq_a">

 <div class="productRate">
     <div style="width: 100%"></div>  
 </div> 
 <input name="rq[2]" id="rq_2" type="hidden" class="rfield" value="5">  
 
    </td>
           </tr>



           <tr>
          <td>
               <b>Качество основы</b>
          </td>
          <td id="rql3" class="rq_a">

 <div class="productRate">
     <div style="width: 100%"></div>  
 </div> 
 <input name="rq[3]" id="rq_3" type="hidden" class="rfield" value="5">  
 
    </td>
           </tr>



           <tr>
          <td>
               <b>УФ стойкость</b>
          </td>
          <td id="rql4" class="rq_a">

 <div class="productRate">
     <div style="width: 100%"></div>  
 </div> 
 <input name="rq[4]" id="rq_4" type="hidden" class="rfield" value="5">  
 
    </td>
           </tr>



           <tr>
          <td>
               <b>Удобство монтажа</b>
          </td>
          <td id="rql5" class="rq_a">

 <div class="productRate">
     <div style="width: 100%"></div>  
 </div> 
 <input name="rq[5]" id="rq_5" type="hidden" class="rfield" value="5">  
 
    </td>
           </tr>



           <tr>
          <td>
               <b>Цена / качество</b>
          </td>
          <td id="rql6" class="rq_a">

 <div class="productRate">
     <div style="width: 100%"></div>  
 </div> 
 <input name="rq[6]" id="rq_6" type="hidden" class="rfield" value="5">  
 
    </td>
           </tr>






     
           <tr>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td valign="top"><input type="submit" name="send_opinion" id="send_opinion" value="Отправить" class="sub" onclick="save_pop_r_only('157'); return false;"></td>
           </tr>
         </tbody></table>
```

Помогите сделать так, чтобы на safari также срабатывало с 1-го клика

Comment: modOffsetX = 5*offsetX%this.offsetWidth; это остаток от деления?

Comment: Честно - не знаю. Брал из интернета.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос таким образом. Для мобильных телефонов отключил выполнение кода

```js
jQuery(".rq_a .productRate").hover (
function(){
 jQuery(this).append("<span></span>");
},
function()
{
 jQuery(this).find("span").remove();
});
```